# Projecting spatial points on a shifted, pacific-centered map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, r-sf, r-sp

This is my first time posting on here after I've already found a lot of helpful answers. I'm going to try and provide all the necessary information here. My problem is the following:

I have a shapefile of FAO fishing regions (http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home?uuid=ac02a460-da52-11dc-9d70-0017f293bd28) and a whaling logbook (https://whalinghistory.org/aowl/AmericanOffshoreWhalingLogbookData.zip), and I want to create a heatmap using ggplot and geom_hex that focuses in on just Sperm Whales in the Pacific (the hotspot of whaling). To have the Pacific as a unitary entity, I shifted my shapefile's projection by 170 degrees with a combination of solutions I found here on stack overflow to create a pacific-centered map that I can then crop into.

When I do that, R generates the correct map, but it does not project my observations onto the map. This is very confusing to me, as I'm using geom_sf in ggplot to project the map (projection-dependent), but geom_hex with a (non-spatial) data.frame as input (which should not be projection-dependent). I did try reprojecting the spatial dataset from which I generated the dataframe to the same projection of my shapefile, but that did not work either.

I'll attach my code and the ggplot output down low, and I'm grateful for any help. I'm fairly confident that my ggplot code bits are fine, as they worked for any map that was not shifted and I just copy-pasted and replaced names.

```
setwd(...)

library(sf)               # handle simple features
library(sp)               # handle spatial dataframes
library(rgdal)            # import spatial dataframes
library(tidyverse)        # essential
library(hexbin)           # graphics
library(magrittr)         # projections


sf_use_s2(FALSE)          # corrects a bug where the longitude scales are not displayed properly

# imports the shapefile as a simple feature dataset
fao_sf <- st_read(dsn=getwd(), layer = "FAO_AREAS_CWP")

# defines desired projection (which is centered at longitude 170)
target_crs <- st_crs("+proj=eqc +datum=WGS84 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=170")

# defines a long & slim polygon that overlaps the meridian line & sets its CRS to match the shapefile

offset <- 180 - 170
polygon <- st_polygon(x = list(rbind(c(-0.0001 - offset, 90),
                                     c(0 - offset, 90),
                                     c(0 - offset, -90),
                                     c(-0.0001 - offset, -90),
                                     c(-0.0001 - offset, 90)))) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)


# modifies shapefile to remove overlapping portions with the polygons
fao_sf_aux <- fao_sf %>% st_difference(polygon)

# transforms the shapefile to the desired CRS
fao_sf_pac_cent <- fao_sf_aux %>% st_transform(crs = target_crs)

# fix for -180/180 break
bbox <- st_bbox(fao_sf_pac_cent)
bbox[c(1,3)] <- c(-1e-5,1e-5)
polygon2 <- st_as_sfc(bbox)

crosses <- fao_sf_pac_cent %>%
  st_intersects(polygon2) %>%
  sapply(length) %>%
  as.logical %>%
  which

fao_sf_pac_cent[crosses,] %<>%
  st_buffer(0) 

# crop into Pacific
pacific_cent <- fao_sf_pac_cent[fao_sf_pac_cent$OCEAN == "Pacific",]


# introduce spatial points data set, assign coordinates and projection, create subset for spermwhales
whaling_shift <- read.delim(...)
coordinates(whaling_shift) <- ~Lon + Lat
proj4string(whaling_shift) <- CRS("+proj=eqc +datum=WGS84 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=170")
spermwhale_shift <- whaling_shift[whaling_shift$Species == "Sperm",]


# introduce the FAO regions as a spatial polygon dataset to be able to use the over() command 
fao_shift <- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer = "FAO_AREAS_CWP")
proj4string(fao_shift) <- CRS("+proj=eqc +datum=WGS84 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=170")

# match spermwhale observations to polygons
sw_shift <- over(spermwhale_shift,fao_shift)

# create dataframe with coordinates, focus in on observations in the Pacific
spermwhales_coords_shift <- cbind(spermwhale_shift@data,spermwhale_shift@coords,sw_shift$OCEAN)
spermwhales_pacific_shift <- spermwhales_coords_shift[spermwhales_coords_shift$`sw_shift$OCEAN`=="Pacific",]

# plot
spermwhales_pacific_cent_map <- ggplot() + 
                                geom_sf(data = pacific_cent, fill = "white") +
                                coord_sf(expand = FALSE) + 
                                geom_hex(data = spermwhales_pacific_shift, 
                                          aes(x = Lon, y = Lat), 
                                          binwidth = c(2,2)) +
                                scale_fill_viridis_c(trans="log10") +
                                ggtitle("Sperm whaling 1790-1910 in the Pacific") +
                                scale_x_continuous(name= "Longitude", breaks = c(120,150,180,-150,-120,-90)) +
                                scale_y_continuous(name = "Latitude", breaks = seq(-90,90,30)) +
                                theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
                                      axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 11, hjust = 0.5),
                                      axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 11, hjust = 0.5),
                                      legend.position = "none")

spermwhales_pacific_cent_map
```

[image: ggplot output]